# TypeScript interface object coming from data fetching

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm new in TypeScript and I'm desperate, need help after spent all day trying to figure about interfaces, I looked all over internet and I'm not able to render a data fetched, because of the of interface typeError.

Here is my code:

```
export interface GalleryTest {
  x: {
    topTitle: string
    id: number
    imageCover: {
      path: string
    }
  }
  i: number
}

const ImageGallery = () => {
  //const [result, setResult] = useState<string[]>([])
  const arr: any = []
  const { exhibitor } = useParams<{ exhibitor: string }>()
  const { data } = useQuery('Collections', api.getData)
  data &&
    data.map((y: any, Firmennamen: string) => {
      if (exhibitor === y.Firmennamen) {
        y.Portfolio &&
          y.Portfolio.map((ele: any, i: number) => {
            ele.value.id = i + 1
            console.log(typeof ele.value)
            arr.push(ele.value)
            //setResult([...result, ele.value])
          })
      }
    })
  console.log(arr)
  return (
    <Gallery>
      {arr.map(({ x, i }: GalleryTest) => (
        <Link key={i} to='page/testId'>
          <div
            style={{
              backgroundImage: `url('https://source.unsplash.com/random')`,
              width: '25vw',
              height: 'auto',
              backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
              backgroundSize: 'cover',
              backgroundPosition: 'center'
            }}
            className='flex-1 block min-h-0 last:mr-1 cursor-pointer rounded-xl drop-shadow-xl filter scroll-align-start scroll-px-9'
          >
            <div className='flex flex-col px-5 pt-24 pb-4'>
              <div className='text-white'>
                {x.topTitle} Smart Logistics Solutions
              </div>
              <p className='text-white font-thin text-xs pb-2'>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed
                diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna
                aliquyam
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </Link>
      ))}
    </Gallery>
  )
}
```

And the eror is: **TypeError: Cannot read property 'topTitle' of undefined**

topTitle is define in the interface GalleryTest.

here is the data fecthed:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXxLE.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error doesn't relate to TypeScript. It's actually a JavaScript error. The problem is `x` is `undefined`. You need to assign it somehow.

One reason (there may be others) it's undefined is because of the `map` function signature. Replace `{ x, i }` with `x, i` (unless GalleryTest is an object with a field called `x`?)

```
arr.map(( x: GalleryTest, i: number) => (...
```

Comment: Hello @daniel I think x is not undefined because is define on the interface GalleryTest, the problem is with topTitle.

Comment: @CapitanDuke that's not how interfaces work. They describe the shape of something, but don't guarantee it fits that mold. Try printing out `x` and seeing what it is. Better yet, try my suggestion and see what happens.

Comment: @DanielKaplan thanks, I've tried arr.map(( x: GalleryTest, i: number) => (...   and now x isn't undefined anymore but when I try to render the title x.topTitle now is undefined -> Property 'topTitle' does not exist on type 'GalleryTest'

Comment: @PeaceBrotherPeace it has to do with the data in that array being incorrect.